# centering image in div

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, position, center

I have a square `<div>` (`70px` x `70px`) which will contain an image of a variable dimensions(Square, landscape or potrait). I want this image to be symmetrically centered inside the `<div>`. how do I get it..?

```
<div class="img-polaroid" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; background-color: black; text-align:center;">
    <image src='.base_url("images/store/images/".$image->image).'  />
</div>
```

**The actual size of the image can be greater than `70px` x `70px`. But it should fit symmetrically in the center.**

I also have to make it cross-browser compatible..
Help Appreciated...

Comment: how it is coming for the given code??

Comment: This is discussed in lengths in stackoverflow. The only relaible way I found was to use javascript. For simple cases tables work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must it be an `<img>` element?

You can set the image as background of the `<div>` with `background-position:center center` - this is very easy to do, not using javascript and cross-browser..

Use it like this:

```
<div class="img-polaroid" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; background:url('.base_url("images/store/images/".$image->image).') center center no-repeat black; text-align:center;"></div>
```

Check this [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuBGt/1/). In terms of browser support I've never come across a browser that doesn't support this.

It is sure to work on:

- Netscape 6+
- Mozilla 1+
- Firefox 1+
- Internet Explorer 4+
- Opera 3+
- Safari 1+

Comment: look at the jsFiddle the image should be centered regradless of the container's position.

Comment: also need to give `background-size:contain;`... that'll make it work perfectly for the image....

Comment: I figured the thumbnails will be at the correct sized.. You are right obviously if their not.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for u

```
.img-polaroid img{display:block; margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: what are your dimensions of image... if it has a fixed height and width u can align it with css.. like with margin 0 auto and play a bit with top margin and align it center. This might help you... automatically vertical align center is not possible you will have to play with margin a bit.

Comment: He wrote there can be 3 different sizes: "variable dimensions(Square, horizontal rectangle or vertical rectangle)"

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table-cell;` for your div with your `text-align: center;` and `vertical-align: middle;`

Below is the code:

```
<div class="img-polaroid" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; background-color: black; border: 1px solid yellow; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;">
    <image src="http://www.gelifesciences.com/gehcls_images/GELS/Link%20Images/Product%20Link%20Images/ImageScanner%20III%2050x50.jpg" />
</div>
```

and here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/eUGb6/

Here you can find more about compatibility issues:

[vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) [text-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp) [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: i cant give any dimensions to the image... coz the image will be rendered and it can be of any dimension.. i have to show it in its original aspect ratio.

Comment: There is no problem if you don't. I have just used them here because I have put a large image.

Comment: Updated my answer. I choosed a samller picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="img-polaroid" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; background-color: black; text-align:center;">
    <image src='.base_url("images/store/images/".$image->image).'  />
</div>
```

should be

```
<div class="img-polaroid" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; background-color: black;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">

 <image src='.base_url("images/store/images/".$image->image).'  />
</div>
```

add display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to do it vertically/horizontally alignment.

First build a holder div:

```
.holder {
display: table;

}
```

Then build a container div:

```
.container {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center
}
```

And in your container, it would be shown everything centered.
I didn't test it yet.. but should work ;p

```
<div class="holder">
     <div class="container">
          <img src="YOURIMAGE" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy :)

```
.img-polaroid {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle

    }
```

check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9hppL/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the display:inline-block and :after for div, like this:

```
div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
div:after {
  content:"";
  display: inline-block;
  width:0;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/wIeKE).Click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/css%2520/img-vertically-center-content-with-css), you can look at other solutions.

Answer (score -1):

This is your ultimate guide to centering things in CSS> http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9hppL/

```
.img-polaroid {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
}

#image {
    background: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Well yes, by combining two of the items you have the answer.